# tq_mutate() and Volume indicators in R

Tags: r, tidyquant

I am using the tidyquant package in R to calculate indicators for every symbol in the SP500.

As a sample of code:

```
stocks_w_price_indicators<- stocks2 %>%
group_by(symbol)%>%
tq_mutate(select=close,mutate_fun=RSI) %>%
tq_mutate(select=c(high,low,close),mutate_fun=CLV)
```

This works for price-based indicators, but not indicators that include volume.

I get "Evaluation error: argument "volume" is missing, with no default."

```
stocks_w_price_indicators<- stocks2 %>%
group_by(symbol)%>%
tq_mutate(select=close,mutate_fun=RSI) %>%
tq_mutate(select=c(high,low,close,volume),mutate_fun=CMF)
```

How can I get indicators that include volume to calculate properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few functions from the TTR package that cannot be used with tidyquant. Reason being they need 3 inputs like `adjRatios` or need an HLC object and a volume column like the `CMF` function. Normally you would solve this by using the `tq_mutate_xy` function but this one cannot handle the `HCL` needed for the CMF function. If you would use the `OBV` function from TTR that needs a price and a volume column and works fine with `tq_mutate_xy`.

Now there are 2 options. One the `CMF` function needs to be adjusted to handle a (O)HLCV object. Or two, create your own function.

The last option is the fastest. Since the internals of the `CMF` function call on the `CLV` function you could use the first code block you have and extend it with a normal `dplyr::mutate` call to calculate the cmf.

```
# create function to calculate the chaikan money flow
tq_cmf <- function(clv, volume, n = 20){
  runSum(clv * volume, n)/runSum(volume, n)
}

stocks_w_price_indicators <- stocks2 %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_mutate(select = close, mutate_fun = RSI) %>%
  tq_mutate(select = c(high, low, close), mutate_fun = CLV) %>%
  mutate(cmf = tq_cmf(clv, volume, 20))


# A tibble: 5,452 x 11
# Groups:   symbol [2]
   symbol date        open  high   low close   volume adjusted   rsi    clv   cmf
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 MSFT   2008-01-02  35.8  36.0  35    35.2 63004200     27.1    NA -0.542    NA
 2 MSFT   2008-01-03  35.2  35.7  34.9  35.4 49599600     27.2    NA  0.291    NA
 3 MSFT   2008-01-04  35.2  35.2  34.1  34.4 72090800     26.5    NA -0.477    NA
 4 MSFT   2008-01-07  34.5  34.8  34.2  34.6 80164300     26.6    NA  0.309    NA
 5 MSFT   2008-01-08  34.7  34.7  33.4  33.5 79148300     25.7    NA -0.924    NA
 6 MSFT   2008-01-09  33.4  34.5  33.3  34.4 74305500     26.5    NA  0.832    NA
 7 MSFT   2008-01-10  34.3  34.5  33.8  34.3 72446000     26.4    NA  0.528    NA
 8 MSFT   2008-01-11  34.1  34.2  33.7  33.9 55187900     26.1    NA -0.269    NA
 9 MSFT   2008-01-14  34.5  34.6  34.1  34.4 52792200     26.5    NA  0.265    NA
10 MSFT   2008-01-15  34.0  34.4  34    34   61606200     26.2    NA -1        NA
```